# Need to save Save DataI in hindi

Tags: php, android, json

I am Create web service for survey app.

In app user can select survey as Hindi or English.

Every thing perfect in English survey.

In English survey I get below json from android to PHP.

```
{"survey_user":"20141112_115344","caste":"","contact":"","datastreams":[{"answer":"Yes","questionID":"61"},{"answer":"Computer","questionID":"62"}],"polling_booth_no":"126","Image_file":"IMG_121415773426063-1492383430.jpg","userID":"12","address":"","email":"","age":"","name":"","gender":"","longitude":75.8138678,"language":"","latitude":30.8962427,"Audio_file":"12_Audio1415773383664-1588847750.3gp","survey_num":"32"}
```

but problem comes when I get json in hindi.

```
{"survey_user":"20141112_115344","caste":"","contact":"","datastreams":[{"answer":"????","questionID":"61"},{"answer":"????","questionID":"62"}],"polling_booth_no":"126","Image_file":"IMG_121415773426063-1492383430.jpg","userID":"12","address":"","email":"","age":"","name":"","gender":"","longitude":75.8138678,"language":"","latitude":30.8962427,"Audio_file":"12_Audio1415773383664-1588847750.3gp","survey_num":"32"}
```

I really dont know where is problem in android or php.

Statically Hindi value is saved in database, after use `mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);`I checked it but dynamically json always give "?????" value. Plesae tell me how I can Resolve.

Comment: Is that hindi words are saving properly on db?

Comment: hindi words is saved in db. but json always give value in "????"

Answer (score 0):

@Amit kumar, You should use

```
    collection " `utf8_general_ci` " in database table field
```

to save your HINDI data and also use

```
   `header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");`
```

at the top of your php file where you retrieve hindi data..

Comment: i also set utf8_general_ci, I already said when i get json from android its every time comes answer value in "??????".